# DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : System.Exception: Couldn't encrypt the storage key. Thumbprint is null

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure Azure service Diagnostic on my Azure worker role (v2.5).
I ran the following powershell command:

```
$storage_name = "xxxxxxx"
$key = "srxxxxxxxxA+A25deaNn7zxS7+dc49qq7iXr57g=="
$config_path="c:\azure profile\test.xml"
$service_name="apidfdffddfng"
$role="ApffdfdWorkerRole"
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key 
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $config_path -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Production -Role $role
```

I am getting following error when I checked the DiagnosticPlugin.log file in that azure worker role machine:

```
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM] Private    setting is loaded
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM] Checkpoint file is presentC:\Resources\{a87df972-08a1-480d-7a47-68fe23705c65}\directory\63df6ac994f84878831af26f1cc71ec2.ApiHooksWorkerRole.DiagnosticStore\WAD0103\Configuration\Checkpoint.txt
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM] Will use local resource directory C:\Resources\{a87df972-08a1-480d-7a47-68fe23705c65}\directory\63df6ac994f84878831af26f1cc71ec2.ApiHooksWorkerRole.DiagnosticStore\WAD0103
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM] System.Exception: Couldn't encrypt the storage key. Thumbprint is null.
at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.StandardConfig.EncryptKey(String key,  String thumbprint)
at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.StandardConfig..ctor(String nameSpace, Int32 eventVersion, Int64 overallQuota, String accountName, String accountKey, String accountUri, String accountCertStore, Int32 retention, String thumbprint)
at Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Plugin.WadParser.Translate(String baseMaResourcePath, Int32 actualDiskQuota, String& fullConfigFilePath)
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Error: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM] Failed to convert    WAD1.1 config to Monagent config format
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [3/19/2015 5:09:00 PM]          
DiagnosticPlugin.exe exit with code -108
```

Can someone help me in identifying where am I doing wrong?

**Update ( 23/March/2015) :** Now I have added a thumbprint into my powershell command which seems to resolve the first issue but now its not creating custom tables. Here is the new powershell command:

```
$storage_name = "xxxxxxx"
$key = "srxxxxxxxxA+A25deaNn7zxS7+dc49qq7iXr57g=="
$config_path="c:\azure profile\test.xml"
$service_name="apidfdffddfng"
$role="ApffdfdWorkerRole"
$certificateThumbprint="792FXXXXCFA9EDC78973XXXXB031CE99"
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key 
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $config_path -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Production -Role $role -CertificateThumbprint $certificateThumbprint
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression that was introduced yesterday and we are working to resolve it now.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce3ab5bf-c9b3-4b11-8a6b-95b1dc3a1819/azurediagnostics-fails-after-role-udpate-with-no-changes-to-configuration-error-failed-to-parse?forum=windowsazuredevelopment for more information and ongoing updates.